# Discharge time series (date format?) + hourly data in R

Tags: r

I have a time series, that spans almost 20 years with a resolution of 15 min.
I want to extract only hourly values (00:00:00, 01:00:00, and so on...) and plot the resulting time series.
The df looks like this:
[3 columns: date, time, and discharge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNoKv.png)

How would you approach this?

Comment: Give us a reproducible example? It is easier for us to see your data structure and help you out!

Comment: How do you want to "extract only hourly values". Are you after some form of time series aggregation, e.g. average/sum every four measurements? Or do you really want to keep only every 5th measurement (corresponding to the full hour)?

Comment: Sort by `Date` then `Time` and keep only every fourth value by using `c(T,F,F,F)` as subset for a quick solution. It would probably be better to convert the data into a timeseries and operate on that

Comment: I want to keep the measurement corresponding to the full hours.

Answer (score 0):

a reproducible example would be good for this kind of question. Here is my code, hope it helps you:

```
#creating dummy data
df <- data.frame(time = seq(as.POSIXct("2018-01-01 00:00:00"), as.POSIXct("2018-01-01 23:59:59"), by = "15 min"), variable = runif(96, 0, 1))
```

example output: (only 5 rows)

---

```
                 time    variable
1  2018-01-01 00:00:00 0.331546992
2  2018-01-01 00:15:00 0.407269290
3  2018-01-01 00:30:00 0.635367577
4  2018-01-01 00:45:00 0.808612045
5  2018-01-01 01:00:00 0.258801201
```

---

```
df %>% filter(format(time, "%M:%S") == "00:00")
```

---

```
output:
1  2018-01-01 00:00:00 0.76198532
2  2018-01-01 01:00:00 0.01304103
3  2018-01-01 02:00:00 0.10729465
4  2018-01-01 03:00:00 0.74534184
5  2018-01-01 04:00:00 0.25942667
```

---

```
plot(df %>% filter(format(time, "%M:%S") == "00:00") %>% ggplot(aes(x = time, y = variable)) + geom_line())
```

[image]